# Need some assistance in Paypal Mass Payment

Tags: paypal, payment-gateway

Whenever i am trying to do the masspay i am getting the following error message.

"We're sorry, but your PayPal account isn't currently eligible to send mass payments. Please contact either PayPal Customer Service or your account manager., masspay not completed"

But, when i tried by test mode, its works fine. do i need to give any permission and any other settings in my live account.? If you need any other details, please let me to know.

Any help could be greatly appreciated.!

[FYI]
I contacted paypal also. They told me, Don't consider about this message, it will work by api.! Again i am going to ask them also. Before that i like to know the reason about it to ask them Clearly..!

Comment: Did you read the message?  `Please contact either PayPal Customer Service or your account manager`

Comment: You'll need to sign up for mass payments before you can actually do them, even with the proper funds and files in place.

Comment: may i know the reason for this down vote.

Comment: @slaks Do you think, i didn't ask them.? They told me, Don't consider about this message, it will work by api.!
again i am going to ask them also. before that i like to know the reason to ask them about it.

Answer (score 2):

Well it's pretty self explanatory. Paypal turns off Mass Payments by default you need to contact Paypal to enable it on your live account.

Comment: i asked them. they said your account has been already activated.

Comment: Call again, or wait. Changes can take some time.

Comment: That information you got is incorrect. MassPay *must* be manually enabled on your account in order for it to work; this applies to both the API as well as the 'MassPay File Upload' functionality.